# How to statically link to antlr-runtime.lib without the dll

Tags: c++, cmake, antlr4

I'm trying to statically link ANTLR 4's C++ runtime library to a program in Windows. The build is done with CMake. However when I run the program it says that antlr-runtime.dll is missing (I don't want to have to provide antlr-runtime.dll as a separate DLL).

Here are the relevant lines from CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(antlr_runtime_lib STATIC IMPORTED)

if(MSVC)
    set_target_properties(antlr_runtime_lib PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "$ENV{ANTLR4_LIB_DIR}/antlr4-runtime.lib")
elseif(UNIX)
  set_target_properties(antlr_runtime_lib PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "$ENV{ANTLR4_LIB_DIR}/libantlr4-runtime.a")
endif()

target_link_libraries(parser_lib_test antlr_runtime_lib)
```

On Mac and Linux it works fine. Also, static libraries that I have built myself also link fine on Windows, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: For link library statically, you need to **compile that library statically**. In you case `antlr4-runtime.lib` is a "definition file" for **dynamic** (`.dll`) library.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I might have to compile the Antlr4 runtime myself, and then look at setting the output library to static only.